# How to solve webview game cross origin problem?

Tags: android, webview, localhost, cross-origin-read-blocking, cross-origin-resource-policy

i have a webview game (html, css, js)
when i run the application using android studio
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
the resources not loading and the cors origin blocks them

but when i run NanoHTTPD (localhost)
the game is good and everything is well
if i want to publish my game on google play, is localhost is allowed and is apk file accept that?
if no, please i want you to help me how to deal with my situation..
im very disappointed :(